# Need for --add-exports <module>/<package>=ALL-UNNAMED

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

When using the Java Platform module system one can add addition exports with the
JVM option `--add-exports <module>/<package>=<reading-module>`. We can use the
value `ALL-UNNAMED` for `<reading-module>`. This gives all JPMS modules and the
*unnamed module* access to the specified package. But the *unnamed module* has
access to all packages of any module anyway. So, in what situations is there a
need for `ALL-UNNAMED`?

Comment: No one should be writing unnamed modules in the first place.  And no one should be modifying a module’s set of exported packages.  Presumably, ALL-UNNAMED would be used for throwaway/experimental code that is trying to access classes/members it normally shouldn’t.

Comment: In a perfect Java world there should only be Java modules. But until this goal is reached we still need means to migrate existing code incrementally. With the concepts of the unnamed module and automatic modules legacy code and modularized code can coexist.

Comment: I agree.  But since automatic modules are fairly easy to implement, I can’t think of too many legitimate uses for ALL-UNNAMED, other than the case I mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that the unnamed module has access to all public packages of other modules is wrong. The unnamed module also has only access to public classes in *exported packages*. Therefore, `--add-exports <module>/<package>=ALL-UNNAMED` makes sense.